# How can I automatically open/close window blinds?

Tags: windows, electric-motor

I live in an apartment where I cannot change anything. I would like to have my blinds open/close via computer (any interface controllable via RPi/Arduino is fine). It's not required to also roll them up/down but would be nice.

The blinds are rolled up/down via a cord, as usual. They can be open/closed via a "stick" that's rotated. My blinds look like this:

[image: Window blinds]

I could image attaching a small rotating motor to the stick to open/close the blinds could do the job.

I found many solutions which require to change the blinds.
Is there a project/solution which just attaches a small machine to the wall next to the window and has an arm to open/close the blends?

Comment: The blinds you have are most likely inexpensive aluminum or plastic types and are not worth the expense of what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A stepper motor driver (shield, I suppose, in Arduino speak) a couple of stepper motors (if you want both functions) and a modest amount of creativity should do it.

The open/close motor could be fitted with a section of rubber hose to slip onto the handle - the up/down one would need a pulley or spool (as for sewing thread) to roll the cord up.